# How do you make a bot add make all the channels in a server read only for a muted role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a bot on a few servers with muted roles set up but I make a muted role, how do i make it be read only in all the channels?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want the "muted" role to be on every server that your bot joins in you would do something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if mutedrole == None:
        await guild.create_role(name="muted", color=discord.Colour(0x2C2F33), permissions= discord.Permissions(send_messages=False,read_messages=True))
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedrole, send_messages=False, send_tts_messages=False
                                  )
```

As you can see the muted role has the permission to send messages set to False, which means that in every channel the person muted won't be able to send any messages.

Next you will want the mute command itself if you don't want to assign it to the person yourself:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # Only admins can mute
async def mute(self,ctx, member : discord.Member):

    mutedrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")
    if member: # If a member has been pinged ([prefix]mute @User)
       await member.add_roles(mutedrole)
       await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been muted!)
```

This way if you ping a User (when you have admin rights) while using this command he will be notified and given the muted role.